# Multiple PolylineOptions on GoogleMap Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline, polylineoptions

I am trying to insert more polylineoptions in my map, I would like to put 3 conditions and based on them choose the color of the line.
With the code I have I can see the correct map portion, but it doesn't show any lines.
Anyone know how to help me?

```
override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap?) {
    googleMap = p0
    val bc = LatLngBounds.Builder()

    val points: ArrayList<LatLng> = ArrayList()
    val locations: ArrayList<Location> = ArrayList()

    val polypoint : ArrayList<PolylineOptions> = ArrayList()


    googleMap!!.setOnMapLoadedCallback {
        foo.bar.forEachIndexed {fooIndex, step ->
            bar.asd.forEachIndexed { index, location ->
                asd.add(location)
                for (point: Location in asd) {

                    val list = foo.bar[fooIndex]!!.asd.chunked(2)

                    if (index < list.size) {

                        val value = getValue()

                        if (value >= 0 && value < 70) {
                            googleMap!!.addPolyline(PolylineOptions()
                                    .add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude), LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
                                    .width(14f)
                                    .color(Color.GREEN))
                        } else if (value >= 70 && value < 150) {
                            googleMap!!.addPolyline(PolylineOptions()
                                    .add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude), LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
                                    .width(14f)
                                    .color(Color.YELLOW))
                        } else {
                            googleMap!!.addPolyline(PolylineOptions()
                                    .add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude), LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
                                    .width(14f)
                                    .color(Color.RED))
                        }
                    }
                }

                points.add(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude))
                bc.include(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude))
            }
        }



        if (points.size != 0) {
            if (points.size < 2) {
                bc.include(points[0])
                bc.include(points[points.size - 1])
            }
            googleMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bc.build(), 60))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your polylines are a single point (start == end) so you probably can't see them.  (Perhaps you meant to go from previous point to current for each segment?)

Comment: @Andy Exactly!!